# Which answer best completes the sequence?

Tags: pattern, visual, number-sequence

[image]

I'm stuck. The middle row is throwing me off. Help, please?

Answer (score 15):

I think it's

> B. $\boxed{\text{C 23}}$

The letter pattern is:

> Take a letter, skip 5, take the next letter, skip 5, etc. 
>  I.e., take 6 steps. 
>  When you hit the Z, just go back to Y, X, ... 
>  So the Y ⟹ U transition “bounces”: Y → Z → Y → X → W → V → U. 
>  This means that we have I -> (H, G, F, E, D) -> C

The number pattern, as @Pat mentions in a comment on the other answer, is:

> Prime numbers. So after 19 comes 23.

Comment: It's actually odd prime numbers, since 2 is also a prime number and it's not there.

Comment: I would actually characterize the numbers as "odd and not composite" since $1$ is neither prime nor composite.

Answer (score 5):

First: I agree with the logic in @Wu33o's answer.

From a purely test-taking standpoint, if I were totally stuck on the logic behind the actual answers, I would go with

> B) C 23, because "C" is the only letter in multiple options and "23" is the only number in multiple options. This means you need to figure out both the letter pattern and number pattern.

This is very much not foolproof of course, but in a timed situation it could be a useful approach for a guess.

Comment: thought about writing this, then saw your answer. This is usually my approach when playing trivia games and have no clue about the question at hand.